# Error XML on ajax POST

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, codeigniter

Hi I have a stie developed in codeigniter and I want to send an xml by an ajax call.
The xml is come from another server. This is the ajax in my view

```
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlfromserver);

            $(function(){
                 $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<?php echo site_url('/backend/provider/all_country_request'); ?>",
                  data: "xml"+xmlDoc.xml,
                  async: false,
                  contentType: "text/xml",
                  dataType: "text",
                  success: function(msg)
                  {
                    alert(msg);
                  },
                  error: function()
                  {
                    alert("error");
                  }
                });
            });
```

This is my controller:

```
public function all_country_request(){
        if ($this->User_model->isLoggedIn()){
            $this->Travco_model->all_country_request();
        }
        else{
            redirect('/backend/user/home/');
        }
    }
```

and this is my simple model:

```
function all_country_request(){
         $xml_str = $_POST['xml'];
         $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);
         foreach ($xml->DATA as $entry){            
            $data = array(
              'currency_code_travco'=>$entry->attributes()->CURRENCY_CODE,
              'currency_name'=>$entry->CURRENCY_NAME,
              'created'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
              'modified'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
         );
         $this->db->insert('currency_travco',$data);
            echo '<br>';
         } 
         
    }
```

This my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<RETURNDATA lang="it-IT" type="COR" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xmlv5test.travco.co.uk/trlink/schema/CountryRequestV6Rcv.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<MESSAGE>All Countries details and relevant city details</MESSAGE>
<DATA COUNTRY_CODE="ABW" CURRENCY_CODE="EUR">
    <COUNTRY_NAME>Aruba</COUNTRY_NAME>
    <CURRENCY_NAME>euro</CURRENCY_NAME>
</DATA>
```

The error that return to me is in the image attached
[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Look up `php undefined index`

Comment: ok but is the correct way? I don0t know if the problem is the xml passed or the variable in post @Pekka웃

Comment: What `data` are you meaning to send to the PHP script? This doesn't look right `data: "xml"+xmlDoc.xml,`? It should probably be something like `data: { xml: "... some XML data...." }`

Comment: Ok, but return me the string couldn't be parsed as XML

Comment: Yes, because you're not passing the XML properly. I think you can use a `=`: `"xml="+xmlDoc.xml,` not sure; the object notation will work in any case

Comment: Again string couldn't be parsed as XML @Pekka웃

Comment: OK, then debug the string. `echo $_POST['xml'];` in the PHP script and/or `alert(xmlDoc.xml)` in the JavaScript

Comment: in codeigniter of you do that into model or controller called by ajax doesn't print something @Pekka웃

Comment: Then debug the string in JavaScript: `alert(xmlDoc.xml)` before doing the Ajax request ((I accidentally clicked that chat link, please ignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of input your PHP scripts will take you need to properly validate before you continue.

In your case a more verbose variant *could* look like this:

```
try {
    if (!isset($_POST['xml'])) {
        throw new Exception('Missing Parameter Attribute "xml"');
    }
    $mode = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($_POST['xml']);
} catch (Exception $e) {        
    $code   = 400;
    $phrase = 'Bad Request';
    header(sprintf('HTTP/ %d %s', $code, $phrase), true, $code);

    $response                 = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response/>');
    $response->status->phrase = $phrase;
    $response->status->code   = $code;
    $response->message = $e->getMessage();
    if ($errors = libxml_get_errors()) {
        $responseErrors = $response->addChild('errors');
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            $responseError = $responseErrors->addChild('error');
            foreach($error as $name => $value) {
                $value && $responseError->$name = rtrim($value);
            }
        }
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/my-app-response-bucket+xml; charset=utf-8');
    $response->asXML('php://STDOUT');
    return;
}


foreach ($xml->DATA as $entry) {
    $data = array(
        'currency_code_travco' => $entry->attributes()->CURRENCY_CODE,
        'currency_name'        => $entry->CURRENCY_NAME,
        'created'              => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'modified'             => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    );
    $this->db->insert('currency_travco', $data);
    echo '<br>';
}

...
```

For the error-condition of serving an request that is missing or invalid data (the *Bad Request*) a proper response is given back. It even has a response body consisting of XML highlighting errors, for example missing data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <status>
    <phrase>Bad Request</phrase>
    <code>400</code>
  </status>
  <message>Missing Parameter Attribute "xml"</message>
</response>
```

or in case of non-well-formed XML (`<?xml ?><fa ke></fa>blurb`) provided:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <status>
    <phrase>Bad Request</phrase>
    <code>400</code>
  </status>
  <message>String could not be parsed as XML</message>
  <errors>
    <error>
      <level>3</level>
      <code>96</code>
      <column>6</column>
      <message>Malformed declaration expecting version</message>
      <line>1</line>
    </error>
  </errors>
  <errors>
    <error>
      <level>3</level>
      <code>41</code>
      <column>13</column>
      <message>Specification mandate value for attribute ke</message>
      <line>1</line>
    </error>
  </errors>
  <errors>
    <error>
      <level>3</level>
      <code>5</code>
      <column>16</column>
      <message>Extra content at the end of the document</message>
      <line>1</line>
    </error>
  </errors>
</response>
```

Comment: Thanks with your answer I can debug well my code and find the problem!

Answer (score 1):

To Send an xml document as data to the server. You Must be set the **processData** option to ***false***, the automatic conversion of data to strings is prevented.
for example :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  processData: false,
  data: xmlDocument
});
```

Good Luck,

Comment: and after to retrieve It isn't data:xml=xmlDocument ?? Or not?

Comment: try as : `var xmlDocument = [create xml document];
var xmlRequest = $.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  processData: false,
  data: xmlDocument
});
 
xmlRequest.done(handleResponse);`

Comment: the problem is in the page.php how to retrieve the data passed?

Comment: oooh, Try to collect data by using
`$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');`